# Difference between pick up and take

Tags: word-choice, difference

For example: 
tell him to be ready at 6 p.m., I will ( pick him up/take him) on the way home.

Which is the correct option?

Could you explain me  and give me  one or two examples, please?

Comment: *I will take him.* makes sense. *I will take him on the way home.* might not. What is your context? I almost wonder if you want *I will pick him up and take him on my way home.*

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two is that **take** means to transport somebody **to** somewhere, and **pick up** means transport somebody **from** somewhere.

> I will take him on the way home.

You might say this if a colleague needs a lift from work, and so you **take him to** his home, on your way from work to your home.

> I will pick him up on the way home.

You might say this if your son needs to get home from school. On the way home from work, you **pick him up from** the school and take him to your home.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible contexts...

> 1 - you're taking him all the way back home with you,
>   or
>   2 - you'll be dropping him off somewhere else *before* you get home.

*I'll pick him up on the way home* is far more likely. This version works for both the above.

*I'll take him on the way home* only works for the second meaning. This is because *on the way home* means ***during*** the journey home (you can't take him all the way home until the journey is *finished*).

It might help to consider these two related constructions...

> 3: *She asked him the way home*
>    4: *She asked him **on** the way home*

...where we don't know *what* she asked him in #2 - all we know is that she asked *during* the journey.

---

TL;DR: Both are valid, but #2 has a very specific meaning that usually *isn't* likely to be intended.